# Short Code across business units

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

Just a question that i did not see in the documentation: If a customer sends a STOP keyword to a shortcode that is shares with many BU's, the customer opt-out for all sends to that shortcode? Includes others BU's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct.

> HELP or STOP keywords created in Enterprise 2.0 top-level accounts
>   apply to all business units within an organization using the same
>   short or long code and satisfy regulatory compliance requirements.

Reference:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_stop_keywords.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks, @Rachid Mamai. Another question: how can i know who unsubscribed from send the STOP keyword

Comment: One way is to use AMPScript in the Stop's response message and check the "Do not send response" checkbox. The code would update a DE with information from the user who sent the STOP keyword..